# Custom user data capture form with auto membership ID

Tags: plugins, membership

In one of the project I am working, I need to capture user data (infact the members data). On the homepage the visitor who want to be a member will click on register which will show a registration form with 22 fields. Once they submit, I want an automated email to be sent to them with a Unique auto-generated membership ID.

(I do not want the members to get a user ID and password for login)

The admin should be able to get an excel download of the user/member data as and when wish.

Any recommended plugin or method for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

A great place to start would be to use Gravity Forms (http://www.gravityforms.com/).  No, I do not work for or get paid to endorse this company, I've just used them for the past 3 years while working with WordPress and have found nothing better.

Gravity forms will automatically store all of the data from the form submission in the WordPress database, and you can export out all of the entries whenever you'd like.  You can also select a date range of the exported data.  Another great feature of this plugin is setting up auto-responders (called notifications) to the user filling out the form.  They have good documentation on how to extend this plugin as well as several add-on's that already exist to increase functionality.

As for setting up the unique member ID, what will you be doing with this ID and where do we need to store it?  There are many ways to hook into Gravity Forms to generate an ID (or you can use the default ID that Gravity Forms provides with every submission), but not sure what you're looking to do with the ID once it's set.  Is it going to eventually be used for letting the user login?  Does it need to be unique per user email address (Gravity forms does have a "unique email" address function that will check the DB if this user has already submitted something)?  Does the member ID need to cross reference with a list of ID's that already exist somewhere?  Let me know what you're looking to do with this ID and what all is involved with it and I can elaborate more on creating/storing it.

Comment: Thanks @mread The users will be basically applying for membership. So upon succssfull submisison I want to give them an application ID. I want it to be in a format like ABC123. It should be a sequential number for each preceding user. Dont have access to Gravity form, but if it will do my job I will buy a license.

Comment: Ok I think I follow but just to make sure: the application ID won't actually DO anything with the user, it's just a way for you to indentify who the applicant is correct?  Like, they apply, get their unique number, you call and ask them to verify that number or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

With much fiddling..I was able to accomplish waht I wanted using CF7 plugin.
The CF7 plugin is just amazing with lots of features for a free plugin.